# How can using more n-gram orders decrease accuracy for Multinomial NaiveBayes classifier?

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, nltk, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I'm building a model for text classification with nltk, and `sklearn`, and training it on the 20newsgroups dataset from `sklearn` (each document is approximately 130 words).

My preprocessing includes removing stopwords and lemmatizing tokens.

Next, in my pipeline I pass it to the `tfidfVectorizer()` and want to manipulate some of the input parameters of the vectorizer to improve accuracy. I've read that n-grams (generally, with n less than improves accuracy, but when I classify the vectorizer outputs with the `multinomialNB()` classifier, using `ngram_range=(1,2)` and `ngram_range=(1,3)` in tfidf, it worsens the accuracy. Can someone help explain why?

**EDIT**:
Here's a sample datum as requested, with the code I used to fetch it and strip the header:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
news = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all', remove="headers")
#example of data text (no header)
print(news.data[0])

I am sure some bashers of Pens fans are pretty confused about the lack
of any kind of posts about the recent Pens massacre of the Devils. Actually,
I am  bit puzzled too and a bit relieved. However, I am going to put an end
to non-PIttsburghers' relief with a bit of praise for the Pens. Man, they
are killing those Devils worse than I thought. Jagr just showed you why
he is much better than his regular season stats. He is also a lot
fo fun to watch in the playoffs. Bowman should let JAgr have a lot of
fun in the next couple of games since the Pens are going to beat the pulp out of Jersey anyway. I was very disappointed not to see the Islanders lose the final regular season game.          PENS RULE!!!
```

This is my pipeline, the code run to train the model, and print accuracy:

```
    test1_pipeline=Pipeline([('clean', clean()),
                         ('vectorizer', TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2))), 
                         ('classifier', MultinomialNB())])

train(test1_pipeline, news_group_train.data, news_group_train.target)
```

Comment: Sure! Added as the edit :-) @seralouk

Comment: Actually, a very good question! What happen if you do not remove the stopwords? ;P

Comment: Please add the code inside the `clean()`